# What is the keystroke code for space bar in applescript?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, quicktime, automation

I am trying to create a applescript which utilises the keystroke spacebar I have this code

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke {Space}
end tell
```

But When I play the script "space" just doesn't work. I don't receive an error message or anything
(the whole code opens a recording software within the script that when spacebar is pressed recording stars but the script doesn't start the recording.)

- [Make Applescript press LShift](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270061/make-applescript-press-lshift)

This post shows how to hold a modifier key left shift and send it to system events, but is the syntax above correct to press the space bar?

Comment: This is actually a decent question, I hope you don’t mind my reopening it for some help and answers.

Answer (score 6):

Your sample code works properly on my machine (running OS X 10.11.6).

If `keystroke space` does not work on your machine, try the following:

```
tell application "System Events"
  key code 49 -- space bar
end tell
```

Here is a list of key codes for your reference:

[image: AppleScript key codes for keys]

Source:

- [*Complete list of AppleScript key codes*](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes)

Answer (score 2):

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 49
end tell
```